# Disable @Webservice loading during start up

Tags: java, web-services, xfire

How to disable @Webservice loading during start up to save some loading time in xfire?

I have a bunch of services with @Webservice annotation. They are all being loaded during the startup and causing a slow startup. I don't want to load these if I test non-services in dev instance. I am wondering if there is a way to disable this by setting system property or something .

Comment: do you mean disable loading the xfire servlet itself during webapp startup?

Comment: Yep. Can I do it by setting some system property ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, in your web.xml, where you configure the xfire servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>xfire</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>-1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

A negative value for load-on-startup means the servlet is only initialized when the container 'feels like it', and for most containers, this means when the first request comes in.

From the servlet specification:

> The load-on-startup element indicates that this servlet should be
>   loaded (instantiated and have its init() called) on the startup of the
>   web application. The optional contents of these element must be an
>   integer indicating the order in which the servlet should be loaded. If
>   the value is a negative integer, or the element is not present, the
>   container is free to load the servlet whenever it chooses. If the
>   value is a positive 128 integer or 0, the container must load and
>   initialize the servlet as the application is deployed. The container
>   must guarantee that servlets marked with lower integers are loaded
>   before servlets marked with higher integers. The container may choose
>   the order of loading of servlets with the same load-on-start-up value.

So consult the documentation for your web container to make sure this has the desired effect in your case.